# error: File to import not found or unreadable: foundation

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, gulp

The structure of my project:

```
project
  assets
    scripts
    styles
      foundation
        _settings.scss
      app.scss
  bower_components
  node_modules
  public
    css
      app.min.css
    js
  bower.json
  gulpfile.js
  package.json
```

I use gulp-sass to compile app.scss to app.min.css and i want foundation scss files to be included in my app.scss

Here's gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('./assets/styles/app.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
        includePaths: ['./bower_components/foundation/scss']
    }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions']
    }))
    .pipe(concat('app.min.css'))
    .pipe(minifyCss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

And app.scss:

```
@import 'foundation/settings';
@import 'foundation';
```

When I change _settings.scss and then run gulp, all of the changes are saved and compiled. But when gulp is watching app.scss and I change something in _settings.scss I get the following error:

```
Error: assets\styles\app.scss
  1:9  file to import not found or unreadable: foundation/settings
Current dir:
    at options.error (D:\Dropbox\foundation-project\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:276:32)
```

The most confusing thing that sometimes I get the same error when I run gulp, and sometimes I don't get this even when gulp is wathing app.scss

Comment: The last phrase confuses me: Does this error occur every time? Or just when being triggered by the watcher? What happens if you run "gulp styles" multiple times? Can you post the watch process, too?

Comment: What also might be: You have two files that are valid for "foundation/settings", one inside your bower component, one in your assets directory. Maybe you get a classical race condition there.

Comment: You were right about two files that are valid for "foundation/settings". Should I delete the one inside bower components?

Answer (score -1):

Your project will compile and run.

I rececive the same alert on phpStorm and it renders just fine, however at one point the foundation framework css was not loading. To fix this issue I did the following:

1) *settings.scss  add '*' on line - @import 'foundation/_functions';
2) in app.scss add the following import: @import 'foundation';

Comment: The OP does not indicate that they are using phpStorm at all, they're using Gulp as their build process.